# How to overload and reuse class constructor java

Tags: java, overloading

I believe this is a rather easy question to answer, and is probably a repost.

Thing is, I don't exactly know what to search for. I've tried searching for generic terms regarding overloading, but I can only find examples of different ways to use different types or number of arguments.

I think it's easier to understand the problem with an example:

Let's suppose I have an `Adder` class, which allows me to add two integers, but I want to be able to call it with only one integer, using `1` as the second integer:

```java
public class Adder {
    int sum;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Adder myAdder = new Adder(3);
        myAdder.printSum();
    }
    public Adder(int a, int b) {
        this.sum = a + b;
    }
    public Adder(int a) {  // Overloading for default behaviour
        return Adder(a, 1);
    }
    public printSum(){
        System.out.println(this.sum);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to add a new constructor for a single integer, where it just calls `Adder(a, 1)` instead, but constructors can't return anything, as far as I'm concerned.

What am I missing to do this?

Comment: The term I believe is, "constructor chaining", and use would use `this(a, 1)` to do it

Comment: [This search](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+call+a+constructor+from+another+constructor+site:stackoverflow.com) of this site would find the term and usage for you (for future reference)

Comment: That's it! `this(a, 1);` was what I was looking for! Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: You're welcome, but more importantly, please see how I searched for similar questions as this is useful to help you search the site for your own future questions.

Comment: Searching for "java overloading reuse constructor" didn't do the trick. Yours was a success, though!